# при создании телеграм бота не получается вывести кнопки 3 вряд 3 в столбик пытаюсь в коде очистить список но не выходит как будет правильнее?

Tags: python, list, aiogram

```
    from aiogram import Bot,types,Dispatcher,executor

    token='&&&&&&'
    bot=Bot(token)
    disp=Dispatcher(bot)
    l=list()
    v=list()
    @disp.message_handler(commands=['startreikin'])
    async def kalk(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer('это калюкулятор')
        m=0
        for k in range(3):
            for s in range(3):
                m+=1
                v.append(types.KeyboardButton(text=str(m)))
            l.append(v)
            v=[]
        l.append([types.KeyboardButton(text=str(0))])
        keybord_1=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=l,rezise_keyboard=True)
        await message.answer(reply_markup=keybord_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем пытаться делать вложенные циклы - ознакомьтесь с документацией aiogram. В том числе - почитайте инструкции авторов: Например, https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/buttons/#reply-builder